# ffmpeg stream file to crtmp - How to change the resolution?

Tags: stream, ffmpeg, resolution

I'm using ffmpeg - streaming local file to crtmpserver (or other server):

```
ffmpeg.exe -re -i file.avi -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -acodec aac -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://256.257.0.0:1935/flvplayback/live
```

How to change the resolution? File has a resolution `1920x1080`, but I want to send only `640x360`.

`-s 640x360` does not work.

Comment: The complete `ffmpeg` console output would be much more helpful than "does not work".

Comment: Does not report any failure. It´s streaming the original resolution without any changes.

Comment: Please show the complete `ffmpeg` console output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-vf scale=640:360`.

```
ffmpeg.exe -re -i file.avi -vf scale=640:360 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -acodec aac -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://256.257.0.0:1935/flvplayback/live
```